# What package should I use for Azure Tables when migrating away from "WindowsAzure.Storage"

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, nuget

I am currently migrating a project that was written for .NET Fx 4.8 using ASP.NET WebApi to .NET 5.0. This project makes heavy use of the package [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) for accessing BLOBs, tables and queues on a Azure Storage account. This package has been deprecated for a while now, stating that is has been split up into several packages.

For Queues and Blobs it is quite clear what I should migrate to. But there seems to be a lot of confusion regarding Azure Tables however.

- First of all in the NuGet package [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) it states that the package to use for tables would be [Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table/). It's a bit confusing because I always thought that "CosmosDB" is something entirely different than "Azure Tables", but maybe I am wrong.
- The description of [Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table/) however states that this package is in maintenance mode and will be deprecated. I should use [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table) instead.
- [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table) however has not been updated for ages and 2.0.0 is in preview for more than two years now. There is also an issue on its GitHub repo that specifically asks if this project is dead - with no answer.
- After searching around, I found the package [Azure.Data.Tables](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables/) to be closest to what I might be looking for. It's updated, looks alive and seems in line (version-number wise) with the other storage packages. Only the naming is a bit off. There's also a blog post from MS in June this year talking about this package being brand new and all, so I guess this is what I was looking for?

Anyway: I found the API of **Azure.Data.Tables** quite similar to **WindowsAzure.Storage**, I just had to make a few tweaks here and there.

But what I am totally missing now is the classes [QueryComparisons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.querycomparisons?view=azure-dotnet) and [TableQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.tablequery?view=azure-dotnet). Are they just gone? Is there are replacement?

An example of the code to migrate would be:

```
var part1 = 
  TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForGuid(
    nameof(SomeEntity.Id),
    QueryComparisons.Equal,
    idValue));
var part2 = 
  TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForGuid(
    nameof(SomeEntity.Category)
    QueryComparisons.Equal,
    category));
return TableQuery.CombineFilters(part1, TableOperators.And, part2);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you currently have which you wish to migrate.

Comment: Just to note Cosmos.Table was updates in 2020 and latest version is 1.0.8. This 1.0.8 has your classes. The preview was updated in 2019 though. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table/1.0.8

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I ended up using [Azure.Data.Tables] (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables/)

Comment: @Hemisphera How do you find replacement classes ?

Comment: For what I required, the new API was pretty much self-explanatory. Most classes have the same name. I just missed a few constants here and there (Query, Comparison). But because of the lack of time I just decompiled the "old" library and replicated what they did there.

Comment: It appears to me that "Azure.Data.Tables" is not deprecated, but "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table" is deprecated., although I use "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table" in my code. I referenced: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/tables?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem. Yes, `TableQuery` from `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tables` is gone, and the references in documentation to `TableOdataFilter` are useless as it doesn't exist.

Looking at this, I found the easiest way to query Azure Storage Tables using the `Azure.Data.Tables` package is to use the [`.Query<T>([predicate])` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.query?view=azure-dotnet). e.g.

```cs
TableClient customers;

var example = customers.Query<Customer>(c => c.Name == "Microsoft");
```

There is also a `.QueryAsync<T>(..)` async version.

If you were building queries with the `TableQuery` there is no direct alternative, but you can use something like [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to combine `.And()` and `.Or()` expressions to create the predicate.

I modified this to create a fluent version:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class to build predicates fluently
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Adapted from source: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx
    /// </remarks>
    public class PredicateBuilder<T>
    {
        private Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression;

        /// <summary>
        /// Add an OR clause
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="expr">new expression</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public PredicateBuilder<T> Or(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr)
        {
            if (expression == null)
                expression = expr;
            else
            {
                var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr, expression.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
                expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(expression.Body, invokedExpr), expression.Parameters);
            }
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add an AND clause
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="expr">new expression</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public PredicateBuilder<T> And(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr)
        {
            if (expression is null)
                expression = expr;
            else
            {
                var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr, expression.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
                expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expression.Body, invokedExpr), expression.Parameters);
            }
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return resulting expression
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToPredicate()
        {
            if (expression is null)
                return (T value) => true;
            return expression;
        }
    }
```

Example usage:

```cs
var query = new PredicateBuilder<Customer>();

if(name != null)
  query.And(c => c.Name == name);

if (isActive == false)
  query.And(c => c.IsActive == false);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the OData syntax or the LINQ syntax with the `Query` method of `TableClient`.

Here is an example of the former with the CreateQueryFilter helper

```
var queryResultsFilter2 = tableClient.Query<TableEntity>(filter: TableClient.CreateQueryFilter($"PartitionKey eq {partitionKey}"));
// Iterate the <see cref="Pageable"> to access all queried entities.
foreach (TableEntity qEntity in queryResultsFilter2)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{qEntity.GetString("Product")}: {qEntity.GetDouble("Price")}");
}

Console.WriteLine($"The query returned {queryResultsFilter.Count()} entities.");
```

Side Note: If you are going to be comparing against the Timestamp column,make sure to convert your values to UTC format, i.e.

```
 var filter = TableClient.CreateQueryFilter($"age ge 21 and Timestamp gt {DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-3).ToUniversalTime()} ");
```

[Source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/samples/Sample4QueryEntities.md#odata-formatted-string)

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty frustrated that the Azure Package Team deprecated my cheese again changing the recipe in the process. After some frustration, I found that basic use cases could be satisfied by applying simple Linq query syntax.

This worked for my needs

```
var tableClient = await GetTableClientAsync("tableStorageKey");
var query = tableClient.Query<LogEntry>(x => x.PartitionKey == "myPartitionKey" && x.EntityType == "Product");
```

Caution: The query isn't super robust, so passing in a `.Contains()` condition will bomb the query. You'd need to implement a post-query after the initial results for additional array parameters.

```
productIds = new string[] { "123456", "234567" };
var tableClient = await GetTableClientAsync("tableStorageKey");
var query = tableClient.Query<ProductLogEntry>(x => x.PartitionKey == "myPartitionKey" && x.EntityType == "Product");
var result = query.Where(x => productIds.Contains(x.ProductId));
```

Answer (score -1):

You should probably have read a little further in [that blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/announcing-the-new-azure-data-tables-libraries/#querying-table-entities) and the [related docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities):

> ##### Querying Table Entities
>
> The TableClient allows the user to create custom queries using OData filters.

```cs
string MyPK = "markers";
string MyRK = "id-001";
string filter = TableOdataFilter.Create($"PartitionKey eq {MyPK} or RowKey eq {MyRK}")

Pageable<TableEntity> entities = tableClient.Query<TableEntity>(filter: filter);

foreach (TableEntity entity in entities)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{entity.GetString("Product")}: {entity.GetInteger("Count")}");
}
```

Comment: `TableOdataFilter` is an internal class now and therefore not available, so the contents of the post are to be taken with caution. It's also not exactly a replacement: `eq`, `or`, `and` etc. is specified literally. Combining a query is not explained.

Comment: Migrating to this Azure storage/table version has been a nightmare...

Comment: It's just amazing to me that that blog post is still up, referring to a now-hidden class, with comments locked, and no pointer to up to date documentation.

Comment: @Kit Yeah - docs for Azure packages are, to put it politely, a s**tshow. It gets even better when you try to unit test them though, because the Azure package teams in their in finite wisdom have decided that they won't provide interfaces for their packages... which means said packages cannot be mocked...